# PIL and matplotlob display same array differently

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I have an array which has the pixel values from 0 to 255. The datatype is uint8. The matplotlib generates the image with some pixels distorted, in the example it is right side of the white ball. I could not figure out the problem here, although I experimented with different datatypes. Any advice?

```
frame = np.array(read_image[case,time,:,:],dtype=np.uint8)

#Plotting with PIL
im = Image.fromarray(frame)


#Plotting with matplotlib
plt.imshow(frame,cmap='gray',vmin=0,vmax=255)
plt.show()
```

PILgenerates:

[image: PILgenerates]

Matplotlib generates:

[image: Matplotlib generates]

Comment: perhaps it's worth trying a different interpolation scheme